# Solving for x - Trig

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Someone mind helping on this? I think have done the question correct but the system isnt accepting my answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532926/solve-for-x-trig-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\sin{2x} = 2 \sin{x} \cos{x}$, we see that your equation is equivalent to

$$2 \sin{x} \cos{x} = \cos{x}$$

or alternatively

$$\cos{x} \left(2 \sin{x} - 1\right) = 0$$

Now $\cos{x} = 0$ has solutions at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$, while $\sin{x} = \frac{1}{2}$ has solutions at $x = \pi/6$ and $x = 5\pi/6$.

---

The only error in your answer is the final $5\pi/2$, where I think you have a typo.

Comment: So my solutions are correct? " {%pi/2, 3*%pi/2, %pi/6, 5*%pi/2}"
and by typo what do u mean?

Comment: @jayson $5\pi/2$ is not correct.

Comment: Ohright, that makes more sense, thanks T. Bongers!